# Copy void* content into SigLib struct SLData_t*

Tags: c++, windows, signal-processing

I am doing an Windows application using C++. I have the next dude.

I have this function where I receive a `void *` with data audio capture:

```
void Pre_proc_mono::PreProcess(void *data, int lenbytes) {
    SLData_t *signal1;
    SLData_t *signal2;
    SLData_t *result;
    signal1 = (SLData_t*)data;
    signal2 = new SLData_t[lenbytes];
    result = new SLData_t[2 * lenbytes - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < lenbytes; i++){
        signal2[i] = signal1[i];
    }
}
```

The loop always fail around 11000, why? What am I doing wrong ? The idea is then do a correlation cross with SigLib library (DSP library). So I need have arrays with limit, not pointers so I am doing this instead. Help?

EDIT:
First, when I said fails I want to say that when loop reaches to around 11000 appears and runtime error.
Second SLData_t is a kind of date of the SigLib library, and the function to doing correlation cross need this variable as input.

Comment: you need to be provide more information about "fail", "11000", and the value of lenbytes.

Comment: And what is `SLData_t` and why do you treat `lenbytes` (which sugests "length in bytes") as length in items.

Comment: The failure can possibly occur because of array index i goes out of bounds for (void*) data. Also check it is not null before using it (though in this case it should have failed on the first access, not 11000).

Comment: Wait so you have `SLData_t` which probably is 4-8 bytes if I Googled correctly (float or double) and `int` lenbytes.

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802332/convert-void-to-sldata-t-siglib

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
void Pre_proc_mono::PreProcess(void *data, int lenbytes) {
    SLData_t* signal1 = reinterpret_cast<SLData_t*>(data);
    const std::size_t signalCount = lenbytes / sizeof (SLData_t);
    // then if you want to copy inside a std::vector
    std::vector<SLData_t> signal2(signal1, signal1 + signalCount);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::size_t` instead of `int`. This *"copy something to other location"* function is the classic example of a signed integer security hole.

Comment: @TeloPenaBarreiro: You have to `#include <vector>` before to be able to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented far better, safe, and simple using `std::vector` instead of manual-memory-management and `std::copy()`:

```
void Pre_proc_mono::PreProcess(void *data, std::size_t lenbytes){

    SLData_t *signal1 = (SLData_t*)data;
    std::size_t data_length = lenbytes / sizeof( SLData_t );
    std::vector<SLData_t> signal2;
    std::vector<SLData_t> result;

    std::copy( std::begin( signal1 ) , 
               std::end( signal1 ) + data_length , 
               std::back_inserter( signal2 ) 
             );
}
```

Comment: the "hard" part is which is the end of `signal1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 ok, you could use `length = lengthbytes / sizeof( SLData_t );` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 not neccesary, just paranoic :)

Comment: audio people really like their chunk of data. And dont forget the result will be used by a code which expect an raw array, not a vector.

Comment: @UmNyobe: No problem. `vector` wraps a raw array. The audio code won't assume memory management, it just wants a pointer to `data[0]`.